laravel with Inertia/vue in subfolder
I deployed my laravel 11 app in a subfolder on my hosting and it works (only public folder is in subfolder, the app itself is in root not publicly accessible off course).
The prod asset build I had to do it locally because of the lack of npm on my webhosting, so locally I work in root, the hosting is on subfolder.
On my hosting I can log in and navigate within the one Page App driven by Inertia and Vue. But page refreshes give a 404.
Because vue rewrites the links to the domain root
so In fact by entering vue I leave

mydomain.com/subfolder/page

and navigate in

mydomain.com/page

And as long as I move within the one-page app everything works, as the routing is done within vue itself and the browser url is just rewritten but not reloaded.
The problem is when I (or a potential user) tries a page refresh in the browser which obviously produces a 404 Not found error as the vue urls do not into account the subfolder installation.
THE QUESTION IS:
I have seen many proposals to solve this with .env and/or .htaccess or grouping the routes in web.php, etc., but all refer somehow to the Laravel Routing itself, not the Vue Inertia route re-writing, much less in one page apps.
I am also very conscious that I or a deployer could simply rewrite all Vue routes to use this subfolder, BUT: I wonder if there's a default param for Inertia/Vue which accounts for that case (installation in subfolder)? A simple param or something which doesn't force too much changes and changes the routes to include the subfolder?
Which is the easiest way to tell Inertia/vue it was installed in a subfolder? Because apparently just changing the APP_URL in the .env file is not enough.
